# The scrollable thing work fine on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: css, html

The  scrollable thing work fine on firefox but not on css...Here is the link http://sherkz.muhammednaveed.com/sherkz/  ...Please help me out what I have to add in it . 
When I remove the position from this then It will display And If absolute position is given which is already there then It's not display . 
Here is the link of actual scrollable
http://uxliner.com/blumax/demos/index-4.html . 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZScN.jpg)

Comment: Please share the piece of code where you are facing issues.

Comment: Hi I already add to this Kindly just click on the links and see the scrollable thing on header and please check on both browser firefox and chrome And you'll get better idea what I'm trying to ask

Comment: @NiDo0o couldn't find anything wrong on chrome.the header is coming down on scroll(i think thats what your issue is,which works fine). make sure to update your chrome to latest version and clear caches

Comment: there is some prob in the jquery part. In firefox id that is getting applied to the div is `id="slide-3238-layer-13"`  & in chrome `id="slide-2800-layer-7"`. check your Jquery why this is happening. and also found that wrong css is getting applied to it. thanks

Comment: Hi Xenio Gracias the below answer work on chrome but now the problem shift to firefox I am not good at jquery tough That's why needed a short and quick help to get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS, For black over you need to put above the slider image div using :before or :after.

The problem here is that the black overlay is overlaying the mouse icon container.

```
.tp-parallax-wrap {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much It works <3 But the problem is now it's not showing in firefox ?